# Laravel: selectRaw with GROUP_CONCAT and DISTINCT ON

Tags: sql, laravel, select, controller, concatenation

I am trying to use `DISTINCT ON` to show only one `drug_code` and to `CONCAT` the `drug_dosage` onto that one distinct `drug_code`.

[image: Table with data]

Here is the output without CONCAT:

[image: Table output]

```php
$all_drugs = HmsBbrKnowledgebaseDrug::selectRaw('DISTINCT ON (drug_code)
    bbr_drug_id,
    hospital_id,
    drug_code,
    drug_name,
    drug_dosage,
    display_flag'
)
->orderBy('drug_code', 'ASC')
->get();
```

As you can see, it works without problems, but I am getting an error once I add `GROUP_CONCAT` with a separator:

```php
$all_drugs = HmsBbrKnowledgebaseDrug::selectRaw('DISTINCT ON (drug_code)
    bbr_drug_id,
    hospital_id,
    drug_code,
    drug_name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(drug_dosage SEPARATOR ",") as dosage
    display_flag'
)
->orderBy('drug_code', 'ASC')
->get();
```

I am not sure why `GROUP_CONCAT` gives a method not supported error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in last

> The get method is not supported for ....

That means you are trying to `get` the request for the route, but in routes/web.php, there is `post` request to that route
So the issue might be that.

I think to try doing a post request, but you might have refreshed the tab or something else, which is triggering a `get` request instead of `post`. So try again a post request and do tell if the error persists or not?